# Fulltext query using elastica

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm new in elastica search.
Can you help me with creating query ? I need search by name.

```
GET /site/file/_search

"hits": [
   {
      "_index": "site",
      "_type": "file",
      "_id": "135",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
         "userId": 0,
         "name": "P1030021j.jpg",
         "extension": "jpg",
         "size": 1256
      }
   }
]
```

Thanks,

Comment: This question makes me sad. Please give more details, context, mappings, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find solution for my problem:

```
{
    "fuzzy_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["name"],
        "like_text" : "Search string",
        "max_query_terms" : 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search by URL:

> GET /site/file/_search?q=name:P1030021j.jpg

Search By Restful API

```
GET /site/file/_search 
{   
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
             "query" : "name:P1030021j.jpg"
         }
     }
}
```